# PySpark, what to do with columns that not always get created to avoid AnalysisException?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, error-handling

I have data incoming in batches and several columns that come from pivoting the values of another column, so the number of columns varies, one of the columns rarely receives any data ('surprise'),

Because this column doesn't always get created and it is in the `.select()` statement, sometimes it interrupts the process throwing and AnalysisException.

I got to solve it like this and it seems to work so far, but I'm looking for a better way to solve this because this doesn't look like good code:

```
try:
    df = agg_sentiment \
        .select('created_at', 'topic', 'counts', 
                'fear', 'joy', 'sadness', 'surprise', 'anger')

except Exception:
    df = agg_sentiment \
        .select('created_at', 'topic', 'counts', 
                'fear', 'joy', 'sadness', 'anger')
```

As you can see I removed 'surprise' from the select statement in the except part. Is there a way in PySpark to handle this type of situations?

Comment: What exact behavior are you looking for? only join when having data?

Comment: @pltc I just edited my post and rephrased it to make it more clear. Yeah, only join when having the data, but the number of columns varies depending on the values another column gets (I pivot the values of this column into these new columns, and one of them rarely gets created because it doesn't get that value often (called 'surprise' in my code))

Comment: so the idea is to check if there is any value available in that surprise column. If yes then join with it, otherwise then don’t, right?

Comment: @pltc otherwise we join it without the 'surprise' in the select statement. 

If in the new batch there are no 'surprise' value, then when the values get pivoted the column doesn't get created and because it's in the select statement, then it throws an AnalysisError

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could check if the desired columns exists in dataframe before selecting columns.

Here is an example

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as fx

# All wanted columns including possible missing ones
colWanted = ['created_at', 'topic', 'counts', 
                'fear', 'joy', 'sadness', 'surprise', 'anger']
colSelectPossible = []

for col in colWanted:
    if col in aggSentiment.columns:
        # Column exists, so save it to select later on
        colSelectPossible.append(col)

df = aggSentiment.select(colSelectPossible)
```

Comment: Sorry my bad, I think my example is misleading people into looking into the join part, the join part is not important, I will edit my example.

Comment: I looked at your updated question. I think my answer also fits. I will update my answer accordingly.